# Commit Kafka Offsets Manually in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

In a Flink streaming application that is ingesting messages from Kafka, 
1) How do I disable auto-committing?
2) How do I manually commit from Flink after successfully processing a message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By [default](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7.1/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-base/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L138) Flink commits offsets on checkpoints. You can disable it as follows:

```
val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer011[T](...)
c.setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints(false)
```

If you don't have checkpoints enabled see [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/release-1.7.1/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-base/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java#L333)

Why would you do that though? Flink's checkpointing mechanism is there to solve this problem for you. Flink won't commit offsets in the presence of failures. If you throw an exception at some point downstream of the Kafka consumer Flink will attempt to restart the stream from previous successful checkpoint. If the error persists then Flink will repeatedly restart for the configured number of times before failing the stream. 
This means that is unlikely you will lose messages due to Flink committing offsets of messages your code hasn't successfully processed.

Comment: Some sink just doesn't have transaction support, nor is it idempotent. Thus we have the requirement to manually manage when to commit ourself.